# How To Model Mapping Table in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm building a Django app that needs to represent which students are in which classes. If I were doing this in SQL I'd have three tables. One for classes, one for students, and then a third table which would be enrollments, for mapping students and classes together.

In Django I could do this with three models. But is there a "Djangonic" way to represent a mapping between two classes?

Comment: you can use a ForeignKey constraint for that!

Comment: Sounds like a ManyToManyField is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Btw, the "thing" you describing is called in general many to many relation, m2m for short. Yes, django has got a very nice way of setting this. Look up django's docs for the term "ManyToManyField".

In your case, in your Student class you could add field like this:

```
classes = models.ManyToManyField(
    'YourClassesModelNameHere', related_name='students')
```

On migration, django will create the intermediary table for you.

Hope this helps.